# How can move a label outside of a filled bar chart in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am pretty new to R and for my class assignment, I have to recreate this plot. [Societal pressure on men](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMcwd.png)

I have problems with the labels in the "All adult men" section, as I cannot figure out how to get the "No answer" tag out of the plot. Since this label's aesthetics differ from the other two, I think I have to separate them, but I am not sure how to get it adequately aligned then. I tried using ggrepel and different smaller datasets, but I have no idea what I am doing. This is what my code looks like now:

```
axis_labels <- c("0%", "10", "20", "30", "40", "50", "60", "70", "80", "90", "100")
order_age <- c("65 and up", "35 - 64", "18 - 34")
labels1 <- data %>%
  filter(q0005 == "No answer")
labels2 <- data %>%
  filter(q0005 != "No answer")

ggplot(data, aes(x = "All adult men", fill = q0005))+
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0.5, color = "black") +
  geom_bar(position = "fill") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = seq(0, 1, by = 1), color = "black") +
  
  geom_text(data = labels2, aes(label = q0005), stat = "count", position = position_fill(vjust = 0.1)) +
  geom_text_repel(data = labels1, label = "No answer", stat = "count", position = position_fill(vjust = 0.1)) +
  
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("Yes" = "#ec703b", "No answer" = "#d1d1d1", "No" = "#8cd9df")) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 1, by = 0.1), labels = axis_labels, position = "right") +
  theme(
    axis.title = element_blank(),
    axis.line.x = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks = element_blank(),
    axis.text.y = element_text(),
    panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major.x = element_line(color = "#d1d1d1")
  ) +
  coord_flip()
```

So how do I move and properly align one of the three tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit of a fiddling ... First I would suggest to compute the counts and percentages manually instead of relying on `stat="count"` and `position="fill"`. Doing so you have all the necessary stats to place the "No answer" label at hand.

Second, to make my life a bit easier I got rid of `coord_flip` and switched the `x` and `y` aes.

Third, the hard part. To place the "No answer" label outside of the plot panel you have to make some room for the label by increasing the plot margin at the bottom and setting `clip="off"`. Placing the label requires some fiddling with the `y` value which also depends on the exported size of the plot. Note, it's important to not use the y aes in this step so that the range of the y scale is not affected.

Fourth, I use a `geom_path` to add the kinked segment connecting the label and the bar. As I add the segment manually I use a `geom_label` for the `"No answer"` which has the benefit that it has a `fill` and automatically adds some padding around the label. This allows for the nice look when placed on top of the path. Note that also switched to `geom_label` for the `Yes` and `No` as `label.padding` allows to fix the padding around the labels or to the end of the bar which could not be achieved via `vjust`.

Finally note that I used `ggthemes::theme_fivethirtyeight`.

Using some fake random example data:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(123)

data <- data.frame(
  q0005 = sample(c("Yes", "No", "No answer"), 100, replace = TRUE, prob = c(.6, .38, .02))
)

data <- data |> 
  mutate(q0005 = factor(q0005, c("No", "No answer", "Yes"))) |> 
  count(q0005) |> 
  arrange(desc(q0005)) |> 
  mutate(pct = n / sum(n), cumpct = cumsum(pct), cumpct1 = lag(cumpct, default = 0))
  
data_no <- filter(data, q0005 == "No answer")

column_width <- .75

x_no <- .5
x_no_path <- .5 * (data_no$cumpct1 + data_no$cumpct)
y_no <- .2

ggplot(data, aes(x = pct, y = "All adult men", fill = q0005))+
  geom_vline(xintercept = c(0, 0.5, 1), color = "black") +
  geom_col(width = column_width) +
  geom_label(aes(label = if_else(q0005 != "No answer", as.character(q0005), NA_character_)), 
             label.size = 0,
             position = position_stack(0), hjust = 0, fontface = "bold") +
  geom_path(group = 1, 
            x = c(x_no, rep(x_no_path, 2)), 
            y = c(y_no, y_no, 1 - column_width / 2), 
            color = "grey50", size = .5) +
  geom_label(x = x_no, label = "No answer", 
             y = y_no, hjust = .5, vjust = .5, fill = "grey95", label.size = 0, color = "grey50") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("Yes" = "#ec703b", "No answer" = "#d1d1d1", "No" = "#8cd9df")) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 1, by = 0.1), labels = ~ if_else(.x == 0, paste0(.x, "%"), as.character(100 * .x)), position = "top") +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off") +
  ggthemes::theme_fivethirtyeight() +
  theme(
    plot.margin = margin(5.5, 5.5, 22, 5.5),
    axis.text.y = element_text(face = "bold"),
    axis.text.x = element_text(color = "grey50"),
    panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major.x = element_line(color = "#d1d1d1")
  ) +
  guides(fill = "none")
```

The plot below was exported as a png using:

```
ggsave("foo.png", width = 2000, height = 400, unit = "px")
```

[image]